# Can I programmatically close a Smart Panel?

Tags: acumatica

I want to run validation when clicking a button that, if the validation passes, would also close the smart panel. Is there a way to programmatically close a smart panel?

Comment: Usually this is solved by doing the opposite, instead of explicitly closing the dialog when validation pass, closing is cancelled by throwing an exception when validation fails. I don't think you can explicitly close the Dialog from the server side, only from UI using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

First - on SmartPanel you need to add a button and set property "Dialog Result" with "OK" value.

> px:PXButton runat="server" ID="OkButton" Text="Ok" **DialogResult="OK"**

Second - you can use the bellow code (it was written stackOverflow editor, but you may understand the ideea)

```
public partial class ARInvoiceEntrySnrExt : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
{
    public PXAction<ARInvoice> paySmartPanelAction
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Payment details", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    public virtual IEnumerable PaySmartPanelAction(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        WebDialogResult result = this.SmartPanelDataView.AskExt();
        if (result == WebDialogResult.OK)
            {
                var isValid = this.ValidateSmartPanelFields() //validation method everithing you may need
                if (isValid == false)
                {
                    throw new PXArgumentException(CstAPMessages.InvalidDetails, (Exception)null);
                }
        }
    }

    public virtual bool ValidateSmartPanelFields()
    {
        bool isValid = true;
        foreach (DataViewDetail detail in this.SmartPanelDataView.Select())
        {
            if (detail.FieldName <= 0)
            {
                cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<DataViewDetail.fieldName>(detail, detail.FieldName, new PXSetPropertyException(CstAPMessages.AmountPaidMustBeGreater));
                isValid = false;
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}
```